# Do all binding energies work like the exchanging force of photons but just in different strengths?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy, strong-force

[image]

Do all Binding Energies use the same force but in different strengths?

Answer (score 2):

First we need to clarify:

1. The nuclei are made of quarks, which are held together by the strong force, that is the color charge. It is mediated by gluons.
2. The nuclei themselves are held together by the residual strong force or nuclear force, which is mediated by gluons and pions.
3. the electron and the nulceus are held together by the EM force, mediated  by photons.
4. there is also the weak force, mediated by W and Z bozons, and gravitational force, mediated by gravitons.
5. they are fundamentally different forces, not compatible, and they are mediated by fundamentally different particles.
6. if all forces would be the same, photons would react to EM charge and would hardly be able to mediate the EM interaction itself.
7. it is true that quarks have EM charge too, and the proton too, so one particle can have different types of charges. If what you are saying would be true, everything would be in a singularity, because it is the repulsive force of electrons and nuclei that give materials volume (that is why things don't get crushed by gravity into a singularity), and it is gravity that pulls masses together so we don't have just atoms randomly flying in the universe.
8. but gravity is only attractive, strong force is attractive (on the short range), and weak force is attractive and repulsive like EM force.
9. it is true that at high energies, the EM and weak force were united. it is true that at the big bang all the forces were united.

[image]